# Signing and aligning APK file(s) **/*.apk in Azure Devops

Tags: android, azure-devops, apk, azure-pipelines, devops

I have been trying to make devops build of android apk and my pipeline fails in Signing and aligning Apk Stage.

I am getting the following error

**##[error]Error: No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\s***.apk**
[image: PIPELINE Definition Snapshot_1]]
[PIPELINE Definition Snapshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwp94.png)

Comment: I cant reproduce same issue on my side. Could you share some details about how your pipeline definitions look like? You can consider sharing the yaml file here so that we can check it for you.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I have attached screenshot of pipeline definition in Question itself as an update. Please look into it.

Comment: Not sure about if your project is xamarin, but the first step of your steps should be a build task instead of a signing task(It should be the second step). [Gradle task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) or [xamarin.android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xamarin-android?view=azure-devops), choose the correct build task and the issue would go away.

Comment: I did the changes after your feedback and now I am getting this error, although the working directory is now set properly. Li-MSFT A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProjectName'. > Failed to notify project evaluation listener. > org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### [error]Error: No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\s***.apk

This error indicates that you don't have a `xx.apk` file generated in default working directory. You can follow steps below to locate the root cause of the issue and resolve that:

1. Leave `gradlew build` task's `working directory` blank and make sure this task succeeds to generate the `xx.apk` file.
2. In Android signing task, use the `**\*.apk` pattern.
3. Make sure the `gradlew build` and `Signing and aligning APK` tasks are in same [Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). If you're using hosted agent to run those tasks, they must be in **same** job within **same** pipeline/[stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) so that the `Signing and aligning APK` task can directly access the outputs of `gradlew build` task.

   Please make sure these two tasks are in same job. If you have specific reason that you have to make them in separate `jobs/stages/pipelines`, consider using [Artifacts-related tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops) to share the files between `jobs/stages/pipelines`.

   Since a job is a series of steps that run sequentially as a unit, different jobs will run in **different** machines though those agents are called hosted windows/linux. So it's recommended to put the two tasks in same job.
4. If the tasks are in same job while the issue persists, set the [system.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs) variable to `true` and run the pipeline again, then you can check the details about the `gradlew build` task.

   [image]

   Then you can find the output path where the `xx.apk` files are generated. After that [copy those files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to Default working directory (`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`) and the signing task can find the file.

Comment: As per point 4, I enabled System Debug Variable to true and apparently there is no log message of apk getting created

Comment: I have attached pipeline definition in question, please have a look

Comment: I have attached pipeline defintion, please have a look. Just for your info, In our pipeline, gradleTask is disabled and powershell script is enabled

Comment: @user9683713 Hmm, where's your gradlew build task !?  If there's no build task which generates the apk file before the signing task, how could the signing task find the missing apk file...

Comment: Note: To sign the apk, you should at least have an apk! You can: 1. Have an apk file published from local machine 2. Have an apk generated from build task in same job, so you need a build task before the signing task 3. The build task and your signing task are not in same job, check my point3~

Comment: I did the changes after your feedback and now I am getting this error, although the working directory is now set properly. @Li-MSFT A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProjectName'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty;

Comment: your answer is correct but build is not happening now because of gradle version mismatch, I will update you if I fix it for once

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help. I think you may need to use the same gradle version like the one used in your local environment to do the build step.

Comment: Issue is solved @Lance. in Power shell I had to use gradleAssemle Debug command. Thank You for initially guiding by the way!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .apk file is not found under working directory of the build agent. Please check code checkout step of the build pipeline and make sure the .apk file is being checked out as part of the build step. You can view the log as well to confirm this.